# Rendering an array of components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to build this array with different jsx components. I have a function where I add components to this array and then return it.

```
let components = [];
switch (obj.type) {
case 'title':
      components.push = (
          <>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
              <h1>{obj.value}</h1>
            </Grid>
          </>
        );
        break;
  case 'subtitle':
        components.push = (
          <>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
              <h3>{obj.value}</h3>
            </Grid>
          </>
        );
        break;
 }

return components;
```

When I try to render it, it renders blank. I would like to know what am I doing wrong, or what is the right approach to achieve this.

```
const ComponentRender = ({ components }) => (
    <div>
      {components.map((component, i) => (
        <div key={i}>{component}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );

return <ComponentRender components={components} />;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning push instead of using the function

instead of `components.push = item` do `components.push(item)`

Comment: feel stupid, thank you for noticing that!! you saved me!

Comment: @comsci_dude haha no worries, we all have those moments!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```js
const Component = ({ obj }) => {
  if (obj.type === 'title') {
    return <h1>{obj.value}</h1>;
  }
  if (obj.type === 'subtitle') {
    return <h3>{obj.value}</h3>;
  }
  return <h1>unkown</h1>;
};
const ComponentRender = ({ components }) => (
  <div>
    {components.map((component, i) => (
      <Component key={i} obj={component} />
    ))}
  </div>
);


//render ComponentRender
ReactDOM.render(
  <ComponentRender
    components={[
      { type: 'title', value: 'title' },
      { type: 'subtitle', value: 'subtitle' },
    ]}
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but no, I was trying to do something like that. I will have the array populated with multiple components.